# Rings isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

What are five ring properties that hold for each ring that is isomorphic to $R=\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, but not for every ring?

Suppose $Q\approx R$. Then $Q$ has unity, $Q$ is not a field, $Q$ is commutative, $Q$ has no zero divisors, and $Q$ is an integral domain. Do these work? Are there others?

Comment: (2,2) is a zero divisor.

Comment: Didn't you have another question about this ring that you deleted?

Comment: It's \cong for $\cong$. Unless you use nonstandard notation.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, I was told my other question was too broad and that I should split it up into manageable segments so that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Does your definition of ring not require that it have unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Q \cong R$.

- $Q$ has zero divisors. $(2,2)$ is one.
- $Q$ is commutative.
- $Q$ is not an integral domain, because a ring is an integral domain by definition iff it's commutative and has no zero divisors.
- $Q$ is not a field, because every field is an integral domain.
- $Q$ has unity (assuming your definition of ring doesn't already require it).

I apologize if I haven't understand what is meant by a "ring property". $Q$ also has finitely many elements.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_{10}\cong \mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_{30}$. It might be easier to characterize that ring.

One characterization is in terms of an idempotent[*]:

> The ring is commutative and there is an idempotent element $e\neq 0$ such that $e+e=0$, with $1-e$ having additive order $30$, and $e$ and $1$ generate the entire ring additively. In $\mathbb Z_6\times\mathbb Z_{10}$, you get $e=(3,0)$. Then $(1,0)=(3,0)+10(1,1)$ and $(0,1)=(3,0)+21(1,1)$.

Or:

> The ring is commutative with identity and $60$ elements, with an idempotent $e\neq 0$ such that $e+e=0$ and $e,1$ generate the entire ring, additively. Same $e,1$ for this case.

Or:

> The ring is commutative with identity and there is an idempotent $e$ of additive order $6$ with $1-e$ having additive order $10$ and $e$ and $1$ generate the entire group additively. Here, $e=(1,0)$.

[*] An idempotent element of a ring is an element $e$ such that $e\cdot e=1$.

Comment: Given the selected answer, it seems like my answer is not what OP was seeking. The properties requested simply have to be properties that are not true for all rings, but not characterize rings isomorphic to $R$ completely.